# Browsers rendering capabilities, limitations and standards

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, firefox, google-chrome

I need good references on differences between browsers in rendering HTML/CSS. and the limitations each browser has.

Any one can help?
much appreciated

Comment: Thank you so much is there anything similar to this for HTML4.01 and CSS2 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is kind a huge question but for html5 you can use this webpage;
http://html5test.com/compare/browser/index.html

Comment: Great Material Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Already a (mostly) solved problem: http://modernizr.com/ can do this for you.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i have used modernizer several times in my projects, but now im investigating in this topic so i only need resources about this topic, much appreciated

Comment: I suggest looking at the Modernizer source code and seeing *how* they do the feature detects, and therefore, which browsers have which features: https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/tree/master/feature-detects